# perl script fails to change group for file uploaded with apache on linux

Tags: linux, apache, perl, cgi

I'm using a perl cgi script to upload a file on Linux using Apache. The file has owner:group set to apache:apache as expected. I want user1 to have access to the file, but not other. The apache user is a member of the default group for user1, as can be seen as follows:

```
[user1@files ~]$ grep user1 /etc/group
user1:x:513:apache
```

The perl script running as apache ends with the following lines:

```
system("ls -l $file")
my $uid = getpwnam( 'apache' );
my $gid = getgrnam( 'user1' );
print "<br />attempting: chown $uid, $gid, $file<br />";
chown $uid, $gid, $file or die "$!";
```

The output below shows the attempt to change the group failed:

```
-rw-r----- 1 apache apache 197927 Jul 19 02:10 /var/www/uploads/testfile.txt
attempting: chown 48, 513, /var/www/uploads/testfile.txt
Software error:
Operation not permitted at /var/www/cgi-bin/upload.pl line 67.
```

Any idea why the apache user cannot change the group for the file?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the permission of uploads folder it might neither have apache ownership nor permission for apache to access.

```
chmod 755 /var/www/uploads
```

then execute the script, it will work.

Comment: The script starts execution by apache as expected and the upload dir has mode uid gid: drwxrwx--- apache user1. The problem is that the chown in the script fails at the end. When I try the same script but change everything referencing apache to user2, then chown works ok.

Comment: yes you have to either give 755 permission (or) add user2 inside a group which has access to uploads folder to solve the issue